# Google Cloud Datastore, how to query for more results

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

Straight and simple, I have the following function, using Google Cloud Datastore Node.js API:

```
fetchAll(query, result=[], queryCursor=null) {
  this.debug(`datastoreService.fetchAll, queryCursor=${queryCursor}`);
  if (queryCursor !== null) {
    query.start(queryCursor);
  }
  return this.datastore.runQuery(query)
  .then( (results) => {
    result=result.concat(results[0]);
    if (results[1].moreResults === _datastore.NO_MORE_RESULTS) {
      return result;
    } else {
      this.debug(`results[1] = `, results[1]);
      this.debug(`fetch next with queryCursor=${results[1].endCursor}`);
      return this.fetchAll(query, result, results[1].endCursor);
    }
  });
}
```

The Datastore API object is in the variable `this.datastore`;

The goal of this function is to fetch *all* results for a given query, notwithstanding any limits on the number of items returned per single `runQuery` call.

I have not yet found out about any definite hard limits imposed by the Datastore API on this, and the documentation seems somewhat opaque on this point, but I only noticed that I *always* get
`results[1] =  { moreResults: 'MORE_RESULTS_AFTER_LIMIT' }`,
indicating that there are still more results to be fetched, and the `results[1].endCursor` remains stuck on constant value that is passed on again on each iteration.

So, given some simple query that I plug into this function, I just go on running the query iteratively, setting the query start cursor (by doing `query.start(queryCursor);`) to the `endCursor` obtained in the result of the previous query. And my hope is, obviously, to obtain the next bunch of results on each successive query in this iteration. But I always get the same value for `results[1].endCursor`. My question is: **Why?**

Conceptually, I cannot see a difference to [this example given in the Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#datastore-cursor-paging-nodejs):

```
// By default, google-cloud-node will automatically paginate through all of
// the results that match a query. However, this sample implements manual
// pagination using limits and cursor tokens.
function runPageQuery (pageCursor) {
  let query = datastore.createQuery('Task')
    .limit(pageSize);

  if (pageCursor) {
    query = query.start(pageCursor);
  }

  return datastore.runQuery(query)
    .then((results) => {
      const entities = results[0];
      const info = results[1];

      if (info.moreResults !== Datastore.NO_MORE_RESULTS) {
        // If there are more results to retrieve, the end cursor is
        // automatically set on `info`. To get this value directly, access
        // the `endCursor` property.
        return runPageQuery(info.endCursor)
          .then((results) => {
            // Concatenate entities
            results[0] = entities.concat(results[0]);
            return results;
          });
      }

      return [entities, info];
    });
}
```

(except for the fact, that I don't specify a limit on the size of the query result by myself, which I have also tried, by setting it to 1000, which does not change anything.)

Why does my code run into this infinite loop, stuck on each step at the same "endCursor"? And how do I correct this?

Also, what is the hard limit on the number of results obtained per call of `datastore.runQuery()`? I have not found this information in the Google Datastore documentation thus far.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [API documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/datastore/1.0.0/datastore) for the Node.js client library for Datastore there is a section on that page titled "Paginating Records" that may help you. Here's a direct copy of the code snippet from the section:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var NUM_RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 15;

app.get('/contacts', function(req, res) {
  var query = datastore.createQuery('Contacts')
    .limit(NUM_RESULTS_PER_PAGE);

  if (req.query.nextPageCursor) {
    query.start(req.query.nextPageCursor);
  }

  datastore.runQuery(query, function(err, entities, info) {
    if (err) {
      // Error handling omitted.
      return;
    }

    // Respond to the front end with the contacts and the cursoring token
    // from the query we just ran.
    var frontEndResponse = {
      contacts: entities
    };

    // Check if  more results may exist.
    if (info.moreResults !== datastore.NO_MORE_RESULTS) {
      frontEndResponse.nextPageCursor = info.endCursor;
    }

    res.render('contacts', frontEndResponse);
  });
});
```

Maybe you can try using one of the other syntax options (instead of Promises). The [runQuery](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/datastore/1.0.0/datastore?method=runQuery) method can take a callback function as an argument, and that callback's parameters include explicit references to the entities array and the info object (which has the endCursor as a property).

And there are limits and quotas imposed on calls to the Datastore API as well. Here are links to official documentation that address them in detail:

[Limits](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits)

[Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Datastore)

Comment: Thanks for your effort.
However, as it stands, this example would run into the same kind of infinite loop as I was puzzled about. It is exactly the same logic, as far as the recursive querying goes.

Comment: After some searching I found the problem is that `NO_MORE_RESULTS` may actually never be returned, even if there are no more results. So this loop would go on forever, as in my case.
Instead, `MORE_RESULTS_AFTER_LIMIT` is returned although there are no more results. But `MORE_RESULTS_AFTER_LIMIT` only indicates that there _may be_ more results.One needs to check in addition if an empty array of results was returned, in order to abort then, if necessary.

Comment: Well I tried. I tend to avoid using the client libraries and leverage the REST API directly. Maybe you can try that as an option.

Comment: Might be that the issue comes up primarily with the datastore emulator (for which it seems, it will *never* return `NO_MORE_RESULTS`, so the example would always recurse infinitely).

I will write that up as an answer when I find time to gather the references together again. The documentation is sorely lacking in many regards, on issues not only as this one, but basically anything.

One should think that Google had the resources to at least provide decent documentation for their APIs. But even offering examples in the documentation which will run into infinite loops. That's really awful.

Comment: Thanks for your care. No, I want to get going with the client library, and still hope that it may all work out. But that might be an idea for an emergency fallback. I'll see how it goes.